# Using if else in Variable expressions(d)

Tags: cplex, opl

Imagine I have the below decision expression in my OPL code.I need to get the value for z..Z is calculating the summation of elements of decision variable na_pur_req[i,j](2d array-1 row & 12 columns).And I only need to get the summation for specific values.(example- J=2 to j=12).So I used a if else ternary operators as follows.But it provide an error as "Cannot use type int for booleans".
1.Could you support me why this error.
2.Is there any way that I can use If else function in dexpr statement.

```
dexpr int z=sum(i in 1..1,j in 1..12) (j>1) ?na_pur_req[i,j] : 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use slicing

```
range I=1..2;
range J=1..12;


dvar int na_pur_req[I,J] in 1..10;
dexpr int z=sum(i in 1..1,j in 1..12:j>1) na_pur_req[i,j] ;

minimize z;

subject to
{

}
```

works fine

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the problem with your expression is but you can achieve your goal in a simpler way in any case: you can filter the j values already in the sum:

```
sum(i in 1..1, j in 1..12 : j > 1)
```

With this your sum will only pick up the desired decision variables and there is no need to have 0 terms in the sum.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Junglas